# Sent email attachment using mailgun library, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, attachment, mailgun

Can anyone please guide me how to send an attachment using mailgun and codeigniter. Searching it from last 3 days and not finding any proper clue that how deal with it. This is my array of data:

```
$postFields = array(
        "from" => $from,
        "to" => $to,
        "subject" => $subject,
        "html" => $html,
        "text" => $text,
        "o:tag" => $tag,
        "o:dkim" => "yes",
    );
```

Please help me that how to append an attachment. Tried appending attachment many times while following answers but got failed to receive any of the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should insert your Mailgun smtp details into email config file located in config/email.php, then you can send emails through Mailgun.
then determine your attachment file using below code:

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/file.format');
```

After set other options mail will send!
For more details you can visit:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

If there isn't any email.php file in the config folder just create it simply then paste and edit below code into it:

```
<?php
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.mailgun.org';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = '';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '4';
$config['crlf'] = '\n';
$config['newline'] = '\r\n';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

?>
```

Comment: There is no email config file attached in library folder.

Comment: Yes, Sometimes there isn't any email.php file in config folder. you can create it simply. I've added sample codes to my answer. @AhsanVohra

Comment: I have already added your code which you shared earlier with me but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Have you added other code parts that explained in CI document? @AhsanVohra